# Next - Auth : Pull image from profile into session

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am building a next.js app with Next Auth. I'm using google, facebook, github, and twitter. In each of these cases, the thumbnail associated with the user is included with the returned profile. However, neither it nor any other part of the profile is included with the session. Only the name, email, and role are included.

How do I pass the thumbnail - or any other part of the profile - on to the session?

Here is the code in the [...nextauth].js file

```
FacebookProvider({
  profile(profile) {
    console.log('Profile Facebook: ', profile)

    return {
      ...profile,
      role: 'client'
      thumbnail: profile?.picture?.url
    }
  },
  clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_Secret
}),
```

Note that the picture should be included with other parts of the profile, but the only parts that carry through are the name, email, and role. Even when I set it manually, it isn't passed through.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a local version with facebook setup, but in the past I've done something similar with Cognito by editing the session callback and doing what I wanted there.

However, just as a note depending on the OAuth provider some details aren't available after the first sign in - I'm thinking about Apple specifically but just something to watch out for.

https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks is the bit in the docs.

You'd likely want something like this:

```
NextAuth({
    providers: [
FacebookProvider({
  clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_Secret
}),
    ],
    callbacks: {
      session: async function ({ session, token }) {
        return {
// see if photo url is available here

          ...session,
        };
      },
    },
  })
```

Comment: I tried this, but by the time it gets to the callback, the data from the profile is gone

Comment: hmm, apologies I had misread your post. As I say I don't have any experience with the facebook one, but I've found this which appears to get the facebook avatar: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/76#99 - it does say it's available by default in 2.0 so it might be worth an issue on the repo if it isn't.